# Rotate storyboard view controller in Xcode 5

Tags: xcode, storyboard, xcode5

I have a little problem...
In Xcode 4.6, we could rotate our views in the storyboard in selecting orientation->landscape 
But I can't find the same button in Xcode 5....

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remember where the Status Bar and Navigation Bar popups were in Xcode 4? The pane on the right? It's called the Attributes Inspector. You'll find Orientation is now there.

Comment: Well i looked, but it was hidden :)

Answer (score 2):

Well if you are still using xcode 4.6 and new to xcode 5.0,and wondering where are the orientations in simulated metrics pane.

Hover your Cursor on to "Simulated Metics" pane and an option called "Show" pops up click on it and you are good to go.

Please Find the below image

Here is Step 1

[image: Tricky Part]

Here is Step 2

[image: Step 2]